# Будет ли утечка памяти, если конструктор бросит исключение?

Tags: память, c++

Есть некая фабрика:

```
TBar * foo()
{
    return new TBar();  // здесь конструктор TBar бросает исключение
}
```

Если конструктор TBar бросит исключение, мы получим утечку памяти, выделенной для нового объекта TBar. Верно?

Comment: Здесь утверждается, что утечки не будет: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, неверно.

Если не рассматривать выделения памяти внутри конструктора TBar, то утечек не будет. В языке C++ объект считается созданным только в тот момент, когда его конструктор завершит выполнение без ошибок. Здесь этого не происходит, поэтому объект никогда не был создан, а, значит, и память под него "как бы" не выделялась. Т.е. компилятор обязан корректно освободить память, в которой будет находится объект, в случае исключения в его конструкторе.

Comment: Ок, этот ответ я уже нашел; благодарю.

Answer (score 8):

Вот что написано в стандарте С++ 2011

15.2.2

> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is
> terminated by an exception will have
> destructors executed for all of its
> fully constructed subobjects
> (excluding the variant members of a
> union-like class), that is, for
> subobjects for which the principal
> constructor (12.6.2) has completed
> execution and the destructor has not
> yet begun execution. Similarly, if the
> non-delegating constructor for an
> object has completed execution and a
> delegating constructor for that object
> exits with an exception, the object’s
> destructor will be invoked. If the
> object was allocated in a
> new-expression, the matching
> deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4,
> 12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.

В общем, если конструктор был прерван исключением, то  вызываются деструкторы всех уже созданных объектов, а динамическая память, выделенная под основной класс, будет освобождена соответствующим delete.

Итого, утечки не будет, в том числе и при наличии базового класса, если, конечно, нет внутренних утечек памяти.

Answer (score 0):

**Утечка будет**, если у класса TBar есть хотя бы один **базовый класс**. В этом случае, если будет брошено исключение в конструкторе TBar, то деструкторы для всех базововых классов вызваны не будут. Поскольку объект еще полностью не был создан.

Если есть опасение, что в конструкторе будет сгенерировано исключение и это приведет к фатальным последствиям для программы, то рекомендуется весь код всех конструкторов помещать в блог try. И придумать способ извещения о корректности создания объекта (типа IsValid()).

```
TBar::TBar()
{
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "Утечка будет, если у класса TBar есть хотя бы один базовый класс." - не факт, т.к. наличие базового класса еще не гарантирует, что невызов его деструктора приведёт к утечке памяти или ресурсов. По поводу вызова деструкторов членов: http://itommyalice.blogspot.com/2008/02/c.html

Comment: @Spym Верно, говорите, но необходимо учитывать, что далеко не всегда можно контролировать конструкторы "базового класса для TBar". А точнее, можно контролировать только если базовый класс сделан вами же. И самого факта не изменишь - деструкторы базовых классов вызваны не будут.

Comment: @Spym ссылка с какой то школьной информацией и нет ничего с наследованием связанного.

Comment: "Далеко не всегда можно контролировать конструкторы "базового класса для TBar"" - не спорю. Насчет школьной ссылки: я и не обещал наследования, речь о деструкторах членов.

Answer (score -3):

Если исключение на перехватывать, то утечки не будет, так как программа аварийно завершится, если же его просто как-нибудь обработать, то утечка будет по понятным причинам,
а если его обработать правильно (с очисткой памяти), то утечки тоже не будет.

имхо

Comment: имхо - прекрасный аргумент.